# Question is locked, but still show up as unanswered while the marked duplicate is answered

Tags: bug, status-completed

Is this intentional? Question [how-is-cloud-computing-security-differ-from-traditional-security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/395/how-is-cloud-computing-security-differ-from-traditional-security) is marked as dupliacate and the question [what-are-security-issues-which-are-specific-to-cloud-computing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/341/what-are-security-issues-which-are-specific-to-cloud-computing) is already answered.

Shouldn't the answer be removed from the unanswered questions category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it so locked questions won't show in unanswered views any more.

Answer (score 1):

This was discussed on [MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66068/merged-questions-still-show-up-in-the-unanswered-list).
The crux of the issue is that @RoryAlsop merged the question without closing it, when in principle it should be first closed, and *then* merged.
We'll be more careful next time... In the meantime I went ahead and closed it off, it;s still a merged question but now it wont appear in the unanswered list.

Comment: Yep - my bad on that one. Always a close first, then merge.

Comment: yeah, but who knew...?